# java swing with functional/declarative programming logic error

Tags: java, swing, functional-programming, logic, declarative

I'm trying to make a login function in java swing with functional programming style, below is my code

```
String username = txtUsername.getText();
        String passwordStr = String.valueOf(txtPassword.getPassword());
        User login = new User(username, passwordStr);

        Optional<User> adminUser = Optional.of(new User("a", "a"));
        Optional<User> user = Optional.ofNullable(login);

        adminUser.filter(u -> u.equals(login))
                .ifPresentOrElse(
                        u -> {
                            this.setVisible(false);
                            HomePageAdmin hma = new HomePageAdmin();
                            hma.setVisible(true);
                        },
                        () -> user.filter(u -> u.login(passwordStr))
                                .ifPresentOrElse(
                                        u -> {
                                            this.setVisible(false);
                                            HomePagePeople hmp = new HomePagePeople(username);
                                            hmp.setVisible(true);
                                        },
                                        () -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Credential")
                                )
                );
```

everything is working fine, if I try to login with credentials other than "a" as username and "a" as password, however when I try to log in to the system with those credentials, it gives the "wrong credential" Pane as seen below

[image]

I also tried various ways with the filter function above with this alternatives

```
        User login = new User(username, passwordStr);
        User loginAdmin = new User("a", "a");

        Optional<User> adminUser = Optional.of(loginAdmin);
        Optional<User> user = Optional.ofNullable(login);

        adminUser.filter(u -> u.equals(login))
```

the code above give the same error and won't accept the logic. However, if I try to change the  `adminUser.filter(u -> u.equals(login))` to  `adminUser.filter(u -> u.equals(loginAdmin))`, it works just fine, however this logic is wrong as the adminUser will always be equal to loginAdmin thus inputting anything into the textbox will allow user to log in to the admin page as seen in example below

[image]

[image]

any help is greatly Appreciated

Comment: Please show your `User` class. In particular, what does `equals` do?

Comment: equals is esentially `==`, well I also tried using `==` but still gives the same result oh and this is actually one of my assignment in uni to change the code to functional/declarative and it's working just fine before, so I can certainly say that there's nothing wrong in my `User` class

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839

Comment: I tried to use the `==` already and it still gives error btw, oh and I used the `equals` for this `adminUser.filter(u -> u.equals(loginAdmin))` and it works just fine as seen in the explanation above, but the logic is just incorrect

Comment: Please edit your question to show your User class. In particular, what does equals do?

Comment: equals is esentially ==, did you not see this comment?

Comment: If the `User` class doesn't override `equals()` (i.e. it is the same as `==`) then it is no wonder that your code doesn't work for the admin user. `new User(username, passwordStr)` and `new User("a", "a")` are two different user objects and according to `==` they are **never** the same object. In Java there is no way that `new User(username, passwordStr) == new User("a", "a")` will be true.

Comment: yes, I just found out that it is not the same object as it will keep on creating new object, I tried to print out the `adminUser` and get this result `Optional[vaccinationsystem.User@7d1dd2ca]` meanwhile the `loginAdmin` give out this result `vaccinationsystem.User@47ffd8e4` are there any way to fix this problem? or any other way to get the `"a", "a"` string

Comment: The solution is simple: properly implement an `equals()` method in your `User` class

Comment: and how can you do that? here's the link to my User class for you to check [User](https://github.com/richardsnj/User-class.git) @tgdavies

Comment: Your class has no equals method, so it is using `Object.equals()` which uses object identity. You need to implement `equals` and compare the username and the password fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by implementing the same logic with the `user.filter(u -> u.login(passwordStr))` code by creating a new method in my `User` class called `loginAdmin` as seen below

```
public boolean loginAdmin(String name, String pw) {

        //file to be scanned 
        String Temp = "a";
        String Temp2 = "a";
        //returns true if there is another line to read  

        if (Temp.equals(Username) && Temp2.equals(Password)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;

        }
    }
```

this fix the problem and is implemented to the login class and here's the updated code

```
String Username = txtUsername.getText();
        String Password = String.valueOf(txtPassword.getPassword());
        User login = new User(Username, Password);

        Optional<User> adminUser = Optional.of(login);
        Optional<User> user = Optional.ofNullable(login);

        adminUser.filter(u -> u.loginAdmin(Username, Password))
                .ifPresentOrElse(
                        u -> {
                            this.setVisible(false);
                            HomePageAdmin hma = new HomePageAdmin();
                            hma.setVisible(true);
                        },
                        () -> user.filter(u -> u.login(Password))
                                .ifPresentOrElse(
                                        u -> {
                                            this.setVisible(false);
                                            HomePagePeople hmp = new HomePagePeople(Username);
                                            hmp.setVisible(true);
                                        },
                                        ()
                                        -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Credential")
                                )
                );
```

Thanks everyone for helping me with this issue